# fxcop custom rules - Inspecting source code to look for new keyword

Tags: c#, fxcop, fxcop-customrules

I would like to avoid instanciating certain class with new, and force to use the factory class.

But I don't understand how to do that.

Can someone show me a little sample ?

Thanks in advance for any help,
Best regards

Comment: Are looking for a sample how to create custom FxCop rules or a sample how to check for class instantiations?

Comment: @TrueWill > with pleasure, but how can I do that ?
@dtb > I know how to create simple rules, but I'm looking for way to analyse how instantiations are done for specific types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that should get you started.  You will need to add your own logic for determining whether instances any given type should be allowed to instantiated via newing.

```
public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
{
    if (member is Method)
    {
        this.Visit(member);
    }

    return this.Problems;
}

public override void VisitConstruct(Construct construct)
{
    base.VisitConstruct(construct);

    if (!this.AllowTypeToBeNewed(construct.Type))
    {
        this.Problems.Add(new Problem(this.GetResolution(), construct));
    }
}

private bool AllowTypeToBeNewed(TypeNode type)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I can use the Type.Interfaces to look for the interface of the factory

Answer (score 1):

This guy has explained well

http://www.guysmithferrier.com/downloads/FxCop.pdf